# Loop until choice within list

Tags: linux, list, shell, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a script which loops until the user chooses a value within a list (single digit numbers from `0` to `9`). This is my .sh script which I try to run in the ubuntu 16.04 shell using the `sh` command:

```
choice=999
echo $choice
until [[ $choice in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]]
do
  read -p "How many would you like to add? " choice
done
```

No matter what I do, I just can't get it to work. Here's a test, to give you an idea of the errors at hand:

```
sh test2.sh
999
test2.sh: 3: test2.sh: [[: not found
How many would you like to add? f
test2.sh: 3: test2.sh: [[: not found
How many would you like to add? 2
test2.sh: 3: test2.sh: [[: not found
How many would you like to add? 3
test2.sh: 3: test2.sh: [[: not found
How many would you like to add? r
test2.sh: 3: test2.sh: [[: not found
```

I've tried so many things:

- Avoiding `until` and using `while`
- Using just singular square brackets `[ condition ]`, or no brackets at all
- Using `=~` to match the regular expression `^[0-9]`

Nothing works. Always that same error. What's going on? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `[[: not found` suggests that you're not using Bash. Either add a `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script, or run it with `bash test2.sh`, or use the standard `[`.

Either way, you can't use `in` like that. One alternative would be to use a `case` statement:

```
while :; do
  read -p "How many would you like to add? " choice
  case $choice in
    [0-9])
      break
      ;;
  esac
done
```

The nice thing about `case` statements is that they allow you to use glob patterns, so `[0-9]` matches any number from `0` to `9`.

If you are planning on using Bash in the end, you can also go for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

until [[ $choice =~ ^[0-9]$ ]]; do
  read -p "How many would you like to add? " choice
done
```

Here, a regular expression is used to match a since digit from `0` to `9`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the second method and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome, I have also edited your question to make it clearer what you were trying to do originally. Feel free to re-edit if you disagree.

Answer (score 0):

`[[: not found` is bash builtin, not sh.
Can you check your she-bang and be sure that it's `#!/binb/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh` ? And the second, run script as `bash scriptname.sh`, not with `sh`.

And finally, try to rewrite your script like that:

```
choice=999
echo $choice
while [[ "$(seq 0 9)" =~ "${choice}" ]]
do
  read -p "How many would you like to add? " choice
  # ((choice++)) If choice=999, script will not read anything. 
  # If 0 <= choice <= 9, script will not never stopped.
  # So, you should uncomment ((choice++)) to stop script running when choice become
  # more than 9.
done
```

Comment: It looks like the script is being run with `sh` (see the top line), although that's not the only problem :)

Comment: @TomFenech missed it, but sh also can be symbolic link to bash. So, try first run script at `bash scriptname.sh`, check she-bang. After that, we'll fix your syntax :)

Comment: bash test2.sh
    99
    test2.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
    test2.sh: line 3: syntax error near `in'
    test2.sh: line 3: `until [[ $choice in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]]'

Comment: OK, wait a moment' I'll rewrite your script corerctly.

Comment: @Alexander check also Tom Fenech's answer. I think it's closer to your case.